# Return Distinct Objects with Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, class

(I'm new in VB.Net) I have these three classes:

```
Public Class Classe_PIVA_Cond

Public Property my_codFiscale As String
Public Property my_presenzaDuplicati As Boolean
Public Property my_listaCondominii As New List(Of Classe_Condominio)

Public Sub New()
End Sub


Public Sub New(codFiscale As String, presenzaDuplicati As Boolean, listaCondominii As List(Of Classe_Condominio))
    Me.my_codFiscale = codFiscale
    Me.my_presenzaDuplicati = presenzaDuplicati
    Me.my_listaCondominii = listaCondominii
End Sub

End Class
```

'==================================

```
Public Class Classe_Condominio

Public Property my_Studio As New Classe_Studio
Public Property my_Amministratore As New Classe_Amministratore
Public Property my_codCondominio As String
Public Property my_indirizzo As String
Public Property my_comune As String
Public Property my_cap As String
Public Property my_provincia As String
Public Property my_codFiscale As String

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public Sub New(studio As Classe_Studio, amministratore As Classe_Amministratore, codCondominio As String, indirizzo As String, comune As String, cap As String, provincia As String, codFiscale As String)
    Me.my_Studio = studio
    Me.my_Amministratore = amministratore
    Me.my_codCondominio = codCondominio
    Me.my_indirizzo = indirizzo
    Me.my_comune = comune
    Me.my_cap = cap
    Me.my_provincia = provincia
    Me.my_codFiscale = codFiscale
End Sub

End Class
```

'==================================

```
Public Class Classe_Studio

Public Property my_codice As String
Public Property my_ragioneSociale As String
Public Property my_pIvaCodFisc As String

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public Sub New(codice As String, ragioneSociale As String, pIvaCodFisc As String)
    Me.my_codice = codice
    Me.my_ragioneSociale = ragioneSociale
    Me.my_pIvaCodFisc = pIvaCodFisc
End Sub

End Clas
```

I would try to return a List of distinct Classe_Studio.my_codice in a List(Of Classe_PIVA_Cond).
Any suggestion?

Comment: A LINQ's [.Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) on the `my_listaCondominii` collection can extract the `Classe_Studio.my_codice` value from the `my_Studio` property. A final [.Distinct()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct) should return you a `List(Of String)` of the distinct property values.

Comment: ok, so it must be done in two steps, but I don't understand ho to implement the code.

Comment: No, not necessarily. Assume you have a `List(Of Classe_Condominio)` called `condominios`. You can then extract the distict list of  `Classe_Studio.my_codice` with: `Dim condominios As List(Of Classe_Condominio) = New List(Of Classe_Condominio)() Dim result = condominios.Select(Function(studio) studio.my_Studio.my_codice).Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but I still have a piece: having to work on the object "Classe_PIVA_Cond" which contains a List of "Classe_Condominio", it is possible to use a single LINQ's Select() function or I have to create a list of objects that contains the various filtered lists and filter it later?

Comment: You `Classe_PIVA_Cond` already has a property that reference the `List(Of Classe_Condominio)`. Use that property as the source (in the previous example it was called `condominios`, same reference, same thing). It only changes slightly if you also have a `LIst(Of Classe_PIVA_Cond)`. Btw, you already have (possibly) an answer here.

Comment: I understood perfectly, thanks Jimi!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
    Dim my_codiceDistinctList = Classe_PIVA_CondList
                                        .SelectMany(Function(x) x.my_listaCondominii)
                                        .Select(Function(y) y.my_Studio.my_codice)
                                        .Distinct()
                                        .ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks for the example Matt.G